# nodejs create a mysql database

Tags: javascript, mysql, database

I have some very basic Node.js code for creating a MySQL database.
I have mysql installed.
My code comes up with a corrupted error message stating that packets out of order at the end.
Application port is 3306.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "75577557"
});

con.connect(function (err) {

    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected!");
    con.query("CREATE DATABASE mydb", function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("Database created");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears the mysql package I used was no good.
I installed a different "mysql2" package and that works great.
A day lost due to a poor package.
I am trying to copy a website from MVC to nodejs.
First task is to create and build a database.
I have so far managed to create database and create all its tables so progressing at last.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the database name in your con object when attempting to connect to your database. The mysql.createConnection() method requires you to specify the database name, as it will fail to connect if no database name is specified. It should look something like this:

```
let con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "75577557",
    database: "database_name"
});
```

Comment: Still has same problem.

Comment: Its still the same. If  I remove the database code and just put a res.end("comment"); I still get the same error. The error goes if I remove the mysql server from the pc. But putting back create database code brings back the error.

Comment: J���
8.0.23�(���q2GW~�ےےے�ےد����������lc 2x[N2�caching_sha2_password�!��ے„#08S01Got packets out of order

Comment: The corrupted error message is a problem with firefox so  I am now using Chrome. I am now using Chrome. The error now is localhost refused connection